# Character index in line with UTF-8 files

Tags: go, utf-8, unicode-string

I'm writing a lexical analyzer for UTF-8 text. When an error is detected, I'm supposed to give the line number and the index position in the line.

The user is expected to identify the location in the line by counting the characters he see on the screen (or on the paper) until he reaches the given index value. He could also use the index in the line of the cursor shown by some editors.

I suppose I can't simply use the rune count as index because some unicode characters have zero space width and are supposed to be hidden markers or combined with a non-zero space width unicode character.

How am I supposed to deal with this ?

Is there a function that is able to give the visual unicode index given a byte slice containing runes ?

Also, do the line index in a file start at 0 or at 1 ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in function to get the "visible unicode index", but it should be reasonably easy to keep track of yourself by keeping a counter of the number of runes you've encountered in the current line for which [`unicode.IsPrint`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsPrint) returns `true`.

Comment: Maybe something like https://play.golang.org/p/KC0cD-S-_2n? I'd have to look up what the correct set of character ranges should be.

Comment: Are you sure about assumption of editors? AFAIK compilers gives errors as byte count, not visual count (e.g. TAB, vs SPACE). Editor will manage it. I would also not assume monospace characters have the same width (or zero), and you may have grapheme cluster, where you could not go between them. I would use: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values and check the different categories [M, C (but TAB, new line, and Co, Cn), Z, as zero width]. I would check editor documentation on how they calculate spaces. East_Asian_Width may also help

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  if I only need to give byte count values, that would incredibly simplify my task and solve my problem. Unfortunately, verifying with visual code, there is a col value in the bottom bar, and it counts multibyte unicode letters as one col unit. I need to check aggregated unicode values.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I tried the combined letter a̎. Visual code counts it as two columns. So a column in visual code is an uncombined unicode value. If you provide an answer with that, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find anything in the standard library, but this seems to do it:

```
package main
import "github.com/rivo/uniseg"

func index(s, substr string) int {
   g := uniseg.NewGraphemes(s)
   for n := 0; g.Next(); n++ {
      if g.Str() == substr { return n }
   }
   return -1
}

func main() {
   n := index("Z a̎ B", "B")
   println(n == 4)
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rivo/uniseg